# Can I see what is happening in the django admin side?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools, django-admin-actions

Is it possible with Django to have an overview of what is happening when I set an object with the admin interface ?
Because I want to give ability to an admin to set some objects, then I want that some modifications automatically impact other objects. But I can't find where a the files or where are the functions called by the admin interface.

I looked into admin.py but it allows me to filter, exclude or display some fields, no interest for my problem.

Have you an idea how to see what is happening in admin side please ?

Thank your for reading

Comment: please provide what you want to achive using admin if you want any modification you have to extend admin.modeladmin class in you admin.py.

Comment: When a change happens on the field TITLE in object LESSON for example, the field SOUND of the same object would be automatically updated, (the sound would be generated with gTTS) so I want to receive a response when the admin changes something and I don't know where to find this response

Comment: if you want to change something when any model changes the learn django signals
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Comment: thank you that's what I was searching